# how to Toast a certain position on a listview arrayadapter<string>?

Tags: android, listview, toast

```
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));


    }



    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

im looking for the proper syntax to get the first position of this populated list to a string so i can put it in a toast or save it to a file, im new at this, if i can display it on a toast i can take care of the rest, thank you

```
Toast.makeText(this,(CharSequence) wordsList.getItemAtPosition(0) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
String firstResult = matches.get(0);
Toast.makeText(getContext(), firstResult,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: thanks im always looking around for hours then i get plain and simple here

Comment: glad i could help. please mark the answer correct if it's your preferred solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
wordList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long l) {
            try {
               Toast.makeText(this,"Position is===>>"+pos , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Nay, cannot get the selected index");
            }
        }
    });
```